# How do I use CodeIgniter to make a double language site/application taking data from MySQL

Tags: codeigniter, multilingual

How do I work with languages in CodeIgniter?
Is it really already an internal resource (a helper or library) or I need an plugin to make it work?
Or it is so simple that I can't believe (or dumb enough not to)?

Answer (score 3):

Just follow this url [Codeigniter's language class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html)

Documentation of `CI` is very good, it will teach you everything in a very simple and elegent way.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways: the integrated one and the prettier one, that is not always possible to use.

If you have a server that is not multithreaded on the PHP (in example if you use PHP-FPM), you could use the popular gettext that makes it very easy to translate strings with applications like [PoEdit](http://www.poedit.net) or online free translation webapps like [Transifex](http://transifex.net).

The code is what follows turns on gettext. Put it somewhere before the controller. In the controller constructor is good enough.

```
// get the current language code
$locale = get_setting('fs_gen_lang');
putenv("LANG=$locale");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
bindtextdomain("default", FCPATH . "assets/locale");
textdomain("default");
```

Then you'd have a folder like this:

```
/my_ci_app/assets/locale/en_UK/LC_MESSAGES/default.po
/my_ci_app/assets/locale/en_UK/LC_MESSAGES/default.mo
```

and maybe also a base file from which you will base translations come from and that on update will update all other translations. I leave it in:

```
/my_ci_app/assets/locale/default.pot
```

Else, you can use the inbuilt language system, that works with strings and arrays. In my opinion, it can end up being a pain to use, but it might be just enough if you don't have many strings in your software. There's also [sites](http://mygengo.com/string/) that help translating in this way, as [CodeIgniter itself](http://mygengo.com/string/p/codeigniter-2-1) does.

Just follow the instructions in the language library and the (probably unnecessary) helper:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/language.html

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/helpers/language_helper.html